# How do you make a HTML page determine which Button to click (when you press the Enter key) without JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net, html, w3c

I have an ASP.NET page with two sections on it... one for registration, one for login... each having a submit button.

When i'm in the login part of the page, i want the first 'submit' button to engage when 'Enter' is depressed. When in the registration part, i want the 2nd 'submit' button to engage when 'Enter is depressed.

Problem: I need the page to be accessible (i.e. i'm not allowed to use javascript)

Anyone got any ideas? :) :(

Comment: I'm using 1 form (multiple forms doesn't play well with ASP.NET)

Answer (score 2):

If the two submits are in different forms (and it sounds as if they should be in this instance) there is no issue. Any sane browser will take the submit button from the form you are in.

Comment: They're in the same form... :(

Comment: That throws the "sane" option right out the window, doesn't it... If you can't finagle separate forms for the two actions, there's really nothing to do for it.

Answer (score 0):

This should happen automatically, as long as the two forms are actually separate forms. In other words, there should be two separate `<form>` elements, one for login and one for registration.

**Edit:**

Browsers determine which submit button to "press" based on the form that has focus. If there are multiple submit buttons in a single form, which sounds like the case here, the browser will submit using the first submit button that it finds. I know of no way to get around that behavior.

You're really asking how to perform one of two actions with a single form, which kind of breaks the form model: a form is designed to perform an action (GET or POST) on a single URL. I can think of one way to work around this behavior, but it is not particularly clean.

**Suggestion:**

I made a crude drawing of what I'm talking about. You basically add two radio buttons to the top of the form, one for login and one for registration. Underneath those you have two fieldsets, one with fields for login and one with fields for registration. The form has a single submit button.

[Click to view full size image http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/5923/boardc.th.jpg](http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/5923/boardc.jpg)

Users without Javascript will check the appropriate radio button and fill in the appropriate set of fields. Users with Javascript have a better experience. If the login radio button is checked, hide the registration fieldset. If the registration radio button is checked, hide the login fieldset.

With proper styling, you can make it look nice. Your logic would have to check the radio button field's value to determine what action to take, but that shouldn't be too hard.

That's all I can come up with, given the single form limitation. This might not be a viable solution at all, depending on your other constraints, but it's all I've got. Good luck, and let me know if you have any questions about what I've discussed!

Comment: This is the right way to go. Login and Registration are two different actions and thus must have 2 separate forms. But good luck doing that with asp.net webforms!

Comment: WHAT THE!!!???? No more than ONE form with ASP.NET??? Oh my god I think I'm having a stroke

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your controls in panels, then set the default button property of the panel to the desired button.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx

Comment: Uses javascript internally I believe.

Answer (score 0):

> They're in the same form... :(

Well, can you not change that? Unless they share fields, they shouldn't have to be in the same form. ‘login’ and ‘register’ sound like two different functions to me.

There is no pure-HTML way to specify a default submit button, much less different default buttons in different circumstances.

Including JavaScript does not in itself make your page inaccessible. As long as it still *works* with JavaScript off you're fine.